# Google Analytics Dashboard API demo not working when implemented

Tags: google-analytics-api, dashboard

I can't seem to get this demo of the Google Analytics embeddable Dashboard working: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

Here is a link to my work area: http://goo.gl/2dfnOX

I copy and pasted all code provided from the sample page, and added the local visualization scripts as required.

Any help would be appreciated.